# Leaving parts of an 'If' statement blank (Quick and Easy Question)

Tags: java, if-statement, correctness

```
if (comparison < 0 ) {
   // result is less
}
else if (comparison > 0) {
   // result is greater
}
else {
  System.out.println(something);
}
```

Hi there, quick question regarding the proper protocol with 'If' statements.
The code above is sort of pseudo-code for what I'm writing.

Basically it compares two strings, if the strings are equal to each other, I want it to keep that information (system.out.println for now, but output written later).

This leaves me with an 'if' and an 'else if' that are of basically no use because I only want exact matches really.

What should be put between the {} of the 'if' and 'else if' (assuming there is a proper way to do this) or is there a better way to code this idea?

Thank you :)

Comment: Why not simply write `if (comparison == 0) { ... }` ?

Comment: I sometimes use such empty blocks, but only in case they help me to make a piece of program look more consistent with the rest of it. Here I see no reason for this.

Comment: @jqno You are making assumptions about the type of `comparison`. :)

Comment: @Tom Hawtin Good point :). But even then, something along the lines of `if (!(comparison < 0) && !(comparison > 0)) { ... }` would still probably be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.equals, like this:

```
if (string1.equals(string2)) { System.out.println("Match!"); }
```

This gives you no superfluous if-statements.

Read more on the [String class API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if two strings are EXACTLY equals, you could do this:

```
if (string1.contentEquals(string2)) System.out.println(something);
```

Comment: Agree.  If the sole intention is to do something if string a == string b then just test for equality; adding code that tests for a less than b and b less than a gives the reader the impression that these are somehow important, which they're not, so they hinder comprehension.

Comment: Why contentEquals? There's no reason to use it for two Strings.

Comment: He/she said that only wants to compare two strings, and if they are the same (or "equals"), do something. Exactly what I answered :).